# Call function once on page load and then everytime when user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have to write a code that counts price before discount. It has to execute once, automatically on page first load, and then listen for changes in input fields. Here's what I have done so far. It runs only once sadly. 
Could anyone tell me how to do it right

```
function promo_price()
{

    jQuery(".form-basket" ).ready(function() {
        var cena = 0;
        var procent = jQuery('#przecenajs').attr("data-procent");
        var stara_Cena=0;
        cena = parseInt(cena);
        procent = procent/100;
        console.log(procent);
        console.log(cena);
        cena = jQuery('.main-price').html();
        console.log(cena);
        cena = cena.substring(0, 5);
        console.log(cena);
        cena= parseInt(cena.split(',').join('.'));
        console.log(cena);

        if (!isNaN(procent) && procent!=0 ) {
            stara_Cena = parseInt(cena * procent+ cena);
                console.log('stara cena procent'+stara_Cena);
             $('.staraCena').remove();
           jQuery('.dostepny3d').append('<span class="staraCena"><del>'+stara_Cena+',00</del></span>');
        }
        else if (isNaN(procent) || procent==0 ){
                 $('.staraCena').html(" ");
        }
    });
}
promo_price();
$('.form-basket').on("click",promo_price);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the whole code inside `$(document).ready()`, rather than using `.ready()` inside the funciton.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function promo_price() {
        var cena = 0;
        var procent = jQuery('#przecenajs').attr("data-procent");
        var stara_Cena=0;
        cena = parseInt(cena);
        procent = procent/100;
        console.log(procent);
        console.log(cena);
        cena = jQuery('.main-price').html();
        console.log(cena);
        cena = cena.substring(0, 5);
        console.log(cena);
        cena= parseInt(cena.split(',').join('.'));
        console.log(cena);

        if (!isNaN(procent) && procent!=0 ) {
            stara_Cena = parseInt(cena * procent+ cena);
                console.log('stara cena procent'+stara_Cena);
             $('.staraCena').remove();
           jQuery('.dostepny3d').append('<span class="staraCena"><del>'+stara_Cena+',00</del></span>');
        }
        else if (isNaN(procent) || procent==0 ){
                 $('.staraCena').html(" ");
        }
    }
    promo_price();
    $('.form-basket').on("click",promo_price);
}
```

Comment: @Ele It would be helpful if you were more specific. I just fixed the syntax error from pasting his original code.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ready()` call should not be in your function.

You can define your `promo_price()` function first and then wait for the DOM to be fully loaded. Then call `promo_price()` and define your click event handler.

```js
function promo_price() {

  var cena = 0;
  var procent = jQuery('#przecenajs').attr("data-procent");
  var stara_Cena = 0;
  cena = parseInt(cena);
  procent = procent / 100;
  console.log(procent);
  console.log(cena);
  cena = jQuery('.main-price').html();
  console.log(cena);
  cena = cena.substring(0, 5);
  console.log(cena);
  cena = parseInt(cena.split(',').join('.'));
  console.log(cena);

  if (!isNaN(procent) && procent != 0) {
    stara_Cena = parseInt(cena * procent + cena);
    console.log('stara cena procent' + stara_Cena);
    $('.staraCena').remove();
    jQuery('.dostepny3d').append('<span class="staraCena"><del>' + stara_Cena + ',00</del></span>');
  } else if (isNaN(procent) || procent == 0) {
    $('.staraCena').html(" ");
  }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  promo_price();
  $('.form-basket').on("click", promo_price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic concept of a event handler. You could of course enhance it by using jquery etc. like putting the first click handler inside $(document).ready - especially if you are referencing a DOM element.

```js
clickHandler(null);

function clickHandler(e) {
  console.log('clicked button with text: ' + (e ? e.target.value : null));
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="clickHandler(event)" value="Click Me"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to put the function declaration within the `ready` function
- Put within the function `ready` the manipulation of dom, event binding, function execution, Etc.
- Replace `jQuery function` with jQuery symbol: `$`

---

```
function promo_price() {
    var cena = 0;
    var procent = $('#przecenajs').data("procent");
    var stara_Cena = 0;
    cena = parseInt(cena);
    procent = procent / 100;
    console.log(procent);
    console.log(cena);
    cena = jQuery('.main-price').html();
    console.log(cena);
    cena = cena.substring(0, 5);
    console.log(cena);
    cena = parseInt(cena.split(',').join('.'));
    console.log(cena);

    if (!isNaN(procent) && procent != 0) {
        stara_Cena = parseInt(cena * procent + cena);
        console.log('stara cena procent' + stara_Cena);
        $('.staraCena').remove();
        $('.dostepny3d').append('<span class="staraCena"><del>' + stara_Cena + ',00</del></span>');
    } else if (isNaN(procent) || procent == 0) {
        $('.staraCena').html(" ");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    promo_price();
    $('.form-basket').on("click", promo_price);
});
```

## Resource

[`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

*jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:*

- `$( handler )`
- `$( document ).ready( handler )`
- `$( "document" ).ready( handler )`
- `$( "img" ).ready( handler )`
- `$().ready( handler )`